# Lane detection with brightness change and shades on lanes?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am currently working on a lane detection project, where the input is an RGB road image "img" from a racing game, and the output is the same image annotated with drawn colored lines on detected lanes.

The steps are:

1. Convert the RGB image "img" to HSL image, then use a white color mask on it (white lanes only are expected in the image) with a white color range to discard any parts of the image with colors outside this range (put their values as zeros), let the output of this step by "white_img".
2. convert "white_img" to Grayscale producing "gray_img".
3. Apply Gaussian blurring to "gray_img" to make edges smoother, so less noisy edges can be detected, producing "smoothed_img".
4. Apply edge detection on "smoothed_img", producing "edge_img".
5. Crop "edge_img" by selecting a region of interest ROI, which is approximately within the lower half of image, producing "roi_img".
6. Finally, apply Hough transform on "roi_img" to detect the lines which will be considered as the detected lanes.

The biggest problems I am facing now are the brightness change and shades on lanes. For a dark image with shades on lanes, the lanes color can become very dark. I tried to increase the accepted white color range in step 1, which worked well for this kind of images. But for a bright image with no shades on lanes, most of the image is not discarded after step 1, which produces an output containing many things irrelevant to lanes.

Examples of input images:

1. [Medium brightness without shades on lanes](https://ibb.co/bWxk7nq)
2. [Low brightness with shades on lanes](https://ibb.co/y849mrz)
3. [High brightness without shades on lanes](https://ibb.co/MMgGf9n)

Any help to deal with these issues will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can normalize the brightness of the lanes?

Comment: I am now trying with deciding the white color range dynamically by building a histogram for the lightness channel of the HSL image, then choosing the lowest lightness value of the lightest pixels which form x% of the image (x is determined by trial and error) to be the lower lightness value bound. Do you mean something like this?